# Getting the following error when using ls in Mac terminal: -bash: ls: command not found

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I am getting the following error when running ls or nano or clear in the terminal...

```
SE-ASLAE002-MB1:~ aslae002$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
SE-ASLAE002-MB1:~ aslae002$ nano newfile
-bash: nano: command not found
SE-ASLAE002-MB1:~ aslae002$ cd ~
SE-ASLAE002-MB1:~ aslae002$ clear
-bash: clear: command not found
```

This is what typing echo $PATH in the command line looks like...

```
SE-ASLAE002-MB1:~ aslae002$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
```

For what ever reason, commands like cd or exit work. It was working fine the last time I used the terminal yesterday, but when I shut the computer down and restarted nothing is working. Any ideas?

---

**Update...**

Changed path to `export PATH=/bin:$PATH` and `ls` now works, but `sudo` `clear` `source` and many other commands aren't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cd & exit are shell builtins.  ls is typically installed in /bin.  /bin is missing from your path.

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
```

should fix it.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! That worked. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, that only fixed `ls`. `sudo` and `clear` and many others still don't work.

Comment: I had to change my `.bash_profile` to from `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATHx` to `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:`. Since I didn't give anyone the information to figure that out, if you edit your answer to reflect these changes, I will give you credit for the answer.

Comment: Added /usr/bin to the command.  Also worth noting, if you're adding this to your .bash_profile you don't need the export.